# How to run gulp file after get last version in visual studio 2015?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

I have a project in visual studio that contain many .js files and now im not send it to source control because i have the .ts that generate it, therefore i would like to compile all typescript files with gulp after get last version of source control.
Are this possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gulp has several bindings on it that you use to make it automatically run after certain conditions are met, as far as I am aware you can not do this after getting latest from source control, however you could do it before/after build, which would ensure when you build your solution your javascript is up to date, look in the Task Runner explorer and you will see the available bindings.

Comment: As you mentioned, i can not execute a script using source control event, therefore im using the "before build" event of task runner. Thank you !